# Как автоматически подставить данные и сделать авторизацию?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Доброго времени суток всем.
Столкнулся вот с такой проблемой.
Есть авторизация. Как можно сделать так чтобы в php автоматически подставить данные "логин" и "пароль" чтобы пропустить форму авторизации.
Я хочу сам подставить логин и пароль чтобы пользователь не вводил.
Код формы авторизации:

```
<?php 
include 'init.php';
if($users->isLoggedIn()) {
  header('Location: ./');
}
$errorMessage = $users->login();
include('inc/header.php');
?>
<title>webdamn.com : Demo Build Helpdesk System with PHP & MySQL</title>
<?php include('inc/container.php');?>
<div class="container contact"> 
  <h2>Example: Build Helpdesk System with PHP & MySQL</h2>  
  <div class="col-md-6">                    
    <div class="panel panel-info">
      <div class="panel-heading" style="background:#00796B;color:white;">
        <div class="panel-title">User Login</div>                        
      </div> 
      <div style="padding-top:30px" class="panel-body" >
        <?php if ($errorMessage != '') { ?>
          <div id="login-alert" class="alert alert-danger col-sm-12"><?php echo $errorMessage; ?></div>                            
        <?php } ?>
        <form id="loginform" class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="">                                    
          <div style="margin-bottom: 25px" class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="email" style="background:white;" required>                                        
          </div>                                
          <div style="margin-bottom: 25px" class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i></span>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password"placeholder="password" required>
          </div>
          <div style="margin-top:10px" class="form-group">                               
            <div class="col-sm-12 controls">
              <input type="submit" name="login" value="Login" class="btn btn-success">                        
            </div>                      
          </div>    
          <div style="margin-top:10px" class="form-group">                               
            <div class="col-sm-12 controls">
            Admin: admin@webdamn.com<br>
            password:123    <br><br>
            User: smith@webdamn.com<br>
            password:123                            
            </div>                      
          </div>    
        </form>   
      </div>                     
    </div>  
  </div>
</div>  
<?php include('inc/footer.php');?>
```

Код для проверки правильности введенных данных:

```
<?php
class Users extends Database { 
  private $userTable = 'hd_users';
  private $dbConnect = false;
  public function __construct(){        
        $this->dbConnect = $this->dbConnect();
    }   
  public function isLoggedIn () {
    if(isset($_SESSION["userid"])) {
      return true;          
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
  public function login(){      
    $errorMessage = '';
    if(!empty($_POST["login"]) && $_POST["email"]!=''&& $_POST["password"]!='') {   
      $email = $_POST['email'];
      $password = $_POST['password'];
      $sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM ".$this->userTable." 
        WHERE email='".$email."' AND password='".md5($password)."'";

      $resultSet = mysqli_query($this->dbConnect, $sqlQuery);
      $isValidLogin = mysqli_num_rows($resultSet);  
      if($isValidLogin){
        $userDetails = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultSet);
        $_SESSION["userid"] = $userDetails['id'];
        $_SESSION["user_name"] = $userDetails['nick_name'];
        if($userDetails['user_group']) {
          $_SESSION["admin"] = $userDetails['user_group'];
        }
        header("location: index.php");      
      } else {      
        $errorMessage = "Invalid login!";        
      }
    } else if(!empty($_POST["login"])){
      $errorMessage = "Enter Both user and password!";  
    }
    return $errorMessage;       
  }
  public function getUserInfo() {
    if(!empty($_SESSION["userid"])) {
      $sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM ".$this->userTable." 
        WHERE id ='".$_SESSION["userid"]."'";
      $result = mysqli_query($this->dbConnect, $sqlQuery);      
      $userDetails = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
      return $userDetails;
    }       
  }
  public function getColoumn($id, $column) {     
        $sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM ".$this->userTable." 
      WHERE id ='".$id."'";
    $result = mysqli_query($this->dbConnect, $sqlQuery);        
    $userDetails = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    return $userDetails[$column];       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Решил сам. Заменив:

```
if(!empty($_POST["login"]) && $_POST["email"]!=''&& $_POST["password"]!='') {   
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
```

На:

```
if($email = "admin@webdamn.com" && $password = "123") { 
$email = "admin@webdamn.com";
$password = "123";
```